# Find the quotient and remainder

Tags: polynomials

Find the quotient and remainder when $x^6+x^3+1$ is divided by $x+1$

Let $f(x)=x^6+x^3+1$
Now $f(x)=(x+1).q(x) +R $  where r is remainder 
Now putting $x=-1$ we get $R=f(-1)$
i.e $R=1-1+1=1$
Now $q(x)=(x^6+x^3)/(x+1)$
But what I want to know if there is another way to get the quotient except simple division.

Comment: There's synthetic division as well, but you do have to divide.

Comment: Are you familiar with "synthetic division"?  It simplifies the outright division of polynomials (Euclidean algorithm) when the divisor is a monic first degree polynomial.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with synthetic division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^6+x^3+1= x^6 +x^5 -x^5 +x^3+1\\ = x^5(x+1) -x^5-x^4+x^4+x^3+1 \\=x^5(x+1)-x^4(x+1)+x^3(x+1)+1\\= (x+1)(x^5-x^4+x^3)+1$$

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track:
$$
x^6+x^3=x^3(x^3+1)=x^3(x+1)(x^2-x+1)
$$
Therefore
$$
q(x)=(x^6+x^3)/(x+1)=x^3(x^2-x+1)=x^5-x^4+x^3
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^6+x^3+1=(x+1)(x^5-x^4+x^3)+1.$$

You may apply so-call **long division method**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this precise case, you can notice that $x^3$ is an obvious factor. You are left with: $(x^3+1)/(x+1)$ Using the remarkable identity $A^n-B^n=(A-B)(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+...+B^{n-1})$ with $A=x$ and $B=-1$ gives $q(x)=x^3(x^2-x+1)$

Comment: Sorry, but $x^3$ is "an obvious factor" of what?  Certainly not of $f(x)$ in this problem.  Likely you have in mind that $x^3$ is a factor of $q(x)$ relatively prime to the "divisor" $x+1$, and can thus be removed to simplify the calculation.

Comment: an obvious factor of $f(x)-1$: The OP as very smartly proved that the remainder is $1$, so you just have to divide $f(x)-1$ by $x+1$.